# Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition missing libraries or installation problem

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I bought a new laptop and installed VS Community 2022 (used 2019 previously). I mostly create VB.Net console applications. I had to update a few of my utility apps and all worked fine. I then created a new app to automatically copy and rename photos from Google Drive to One Drive but I was surprised when standard libraries appear to be missing. For example:

```
Dim image As Bitmap = New Bitmap(Fpath)
```

shows a red underline below both Bitmaps and reports bitmap is not defined. Even if I change this to System.Drawing.Bitmap, it still says undefined. If I do type in System.Drawing, then intellisense shows only a few options Classes, Structures, etc. like Color, ColorConverter, etc. I had the same problem with System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes.

I uninstalled and reinstalled, selecting more options in case it needs other things. The System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes now works but System.Drawing.Bitmap is still undefined.

I can go to the menu item Project / Add Project Reference... and select COM, search for Drawing and 2 are shown (2.0 and 2.4). Checking either reports no errors however when I go back again, they remain unchecked.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using an unusual project type possibly?

Comment: If you have built a .Net 5 or .Net 6 Console app, open up the Project configuration file (right-click on the starting Project in Solution Explorer `-> Edit Project File`), add `<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>` and change, e.g., `<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>` to `<TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>` -- Now your Console app is no longer cross-platform and the assemblies used in WinForms are available. Add the directive: `Using System.Drawing`

Comment: OK, that seems to have worked. Do I have to do that for every app I build? Why would I have to do that? Thanks anyway, solved the current problem.

Comment: If you build a **.Net 5+** Console app and you want to reference assemblies that are not included in that Template, you have to modify the Project's file to include them. As mentioned, importing WinForms assemblies, your Console app is no longer cross-platform (one the reasons why those assemblies are not included) -- If you build a **.Net Framework** Console app, you have to add the References to the WinForms assemblies nonetheless, just in a different way.

Comment: Thanks, all very confusing to me but I'm sure it makes sense to others. My app is working so I'll just have to remember for anything else I do in the future. Thanks Jimi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the .NET Framework, the `Bitmap` and `Color` types are both defined in the *System.Drawing.dll* assembly, so being able to access one would mean being able to access the other. In .NET Core, the `Color` structure is defined in the *System.Drawing.Primitives.dll* assembly, while the `Bitmap` class is defined in the *System.Drawing.Common.dll*. The former is a standard part of .NET Core and is cross-platform while the latter is part of the platform extensions that is specific to Windows.

As you have access to `Color` and not `Bitmap`, you have presumably created a project targeting .NET Core rather than .NET Framework. Note that .NET 5 and later are based on .NET Core. You need to either install the appropriate NuGet package to reference the appropriate assembly or else create a new project targeting .NET Framework. All the VS project templates that target .NET Framework say so in the name.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was sure I had picked console, visual basic and .Net. I recreated a new app and made sure it was .NET and not .Core and got identical results. What I did notice in the Solution Explorer under Dependencies \ Frameworks is that it only listed Microsoft.NETCore.App even though I had selected .NET. After I applied the fix above from Jimi, I then listed Microsoft.NETCore.App and Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.WindowsForms. It seems for some reason that when I create a new .NET app, it is only loading .NETCore. Thanks anyway for the info.

Comment: You seem to have missed the part where I said that .NET 5 and 6 are based on .NET Core. You need to select .NET Framework specifically, the latest version of which is 4.8. As I already said in the answer, if you want to target .NET Framework then you need to select a project template that explicitly states that it is for .NET Framework, otherwise you're targeting .NET Core. If you are targeting .NET Core then you can simply install the System.Drawing.Common NuGet package. I've stated all this in the answer but you seem to have missed all of it.

Comment: OK, thanks. Don't misunderstand my lack of understanding with not trying to understand.  It seems that what I would have referred to as .NET in the past is now .NET Framework and now .NET is .NET Core. I will have another attempt when I get back to the laptop but will assume this is the issue and I've marked this as accepted answer. Thanks for the help.